# Object not initialized error when looping over a List in Dynamics AX?

Tags: axapta, ax, dynamics-ax-2012

The Problem:

- I have a list with Objects as elements.
- I use enumerator to loop over the list.
- While looping I assign elements to a variable object with the same type as the element.
- When I call a method on the object, but I get the following error-message:

> MyClass object not initialized.

I think I must cast, but don't know how to do this in Dynamics AX.

I develop in MS Dynamics AX 2012.

```
MyExampleDataContract exampleDataContract = new MyExampleDataContract();
while (listEnumerator.moveNext())
{
    exampleDataContract = listEnumerator.current();
    info(exampleDataContract.parmCustomerId()); //This gives an error.
}
```

Comment: Here it is :), could you show me how to cast in AX ?

Comment: Show the code that fills the list.

Comment: `exampleDataContract = listEnumerator.current() as MyExampleDataContract;` Your new is not needed.

Comment: Now it says: The type current must designate a compatible class, an interface, or a table.

Comment: I used the Debugger and I noticed that the listEnumerator is not uninitialized

Comment: Show the code that fills the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A list element can be null.

```
List l = new List(Types::Class);
;
l.addEnd(null);
info(int2str(l.elements()));
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution was: Before inserting elements in the list they should be instantiated first.

```
for (counter = 1; counter <= 3; counter++)
{
    exampleDataContract = new MyExampleDataContract(); // This is what I missed :)
    exampleDataContract.init("DEV-000000000" + int2str(counter));
    myList.addEnd(exampleDataContract);
}
```